# Multi line equation in a huxtable cell

Tags: equation, quarto, huxtable

This is about adding equations to huxtable table cells for pdf output using Quarto/RMarkdown. I'm able to put in-line latex equations in huxtable cells, and jerry-rigged a 2-line equation using \frac{top line}{bottom line}. However, I now have a four line equation to put in a cell and the usual `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` approach gives me errors. In LaTex the equation is (using \ for escaped terms.

```
bc1 <- '\\begin{align*}   
  \\text{Boundary } &\\text{and Initial Conditions}\\ 
  S_{\\ell} &= S_{\\ell, b}\ \ @r = R_s\\  
  \\frac{\\partial S_{\\ell}}{\\partial r} &= 0\ \ \ \ \ @r = R_p\\  
  S_{\\ell,i} &= S_{\\ell,i}\ \ @ t = 0
 \\end{align*}'
```

Then put it in a table cell. I don't know if this is possible.